# How to run python code locally but use cloud Compute resources to execute?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a have a somewhat heavy python notebook I'd like to run on GCP, but am having some trouble with libraries breaking ect that I will slowly chip away at. In the meantime, I'd like to know (if possible) how to run my notebook from my local machine but place the workload of execution onto some cloud Compute resources? This way my code could be called the way it's been set up on my local machine. A simple solution would have been to upload a custom image of my local windows machine, but you can't do that on GCP free trial and I'm a tight student!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** As you noticed, "upload a custom image of my local windows machine" to GCE is unfeasible due to the free trial program limitations.

[Google Cloud Platform Free Tier > 12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial):

> Program coverage.
> Your free trial credit applies to all Google Cloud resources, with the following exceptions:
>
> - You can't create VM instances that are based on Windows Server images.
>   You must [upgrade your account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) to perform any of the actions in the preceding list.

**2.** Nested virtualization is unlikely to work in this case either.

[Compute Engine > Doc > Enabling nested virtualization for VM instances > Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances):

> Restrictions
>
> - Nested virtualization is supported only for KVM-based hypervisors running on Linux instances. Hyper-V, ESX, and Xen hypervisors are not supported.
> - Windows VMs do not support nested virtualization; that is, host VMs must run a Linux OS. However, nested VMs can run certain Windows OSes (described below).

> [Tested KVM versions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#tested_os_versions):

> - Debian 9 with kernel version 4.9 hosting the following nested VMs:
>
>   - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Edition

**3.** Linux VM in GCE with Python and Jupyter software could be considered.

[Project Jupyter > Installing the Jupyter Software](https://jupyter.org/install):

[JupyterLab 2.1.5 documentation > Installation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html#pip):

> If you use pip, you can install it with:
> $ `pip install jupyterlab`

There are many installation examples out there apart from official documentation. For example this one:

[How To Set Up Jupyter Notebook with Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04):

> Step 1 — Set Up Python
> $ `sudo apt update`
> $ `sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev`
>
> Step 2 — Create a Python Virtual Environment for Jupyter
> $ `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`
> $ `sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv`
> $ `mkdir ~/my_project_dir`
> $ `cd ~/my_project_dir`
> $ `virtualenv my_project_env`
>
> Step 3 — Install Jupyter
> $ `pip install jupyter`
>
> Step 4 — Run Jupyter Notebook
> $ `jupyter notebook`

**4.** Managed Jupyter tool - Google Cloud Datalab - could be a solution in this case. It is available as a free trial.

[Cloud Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab):

> Integrated and open source
> Cloud Datalab is built on Jupyter (formerly
> IPython), which boasts a thriving ecosystem of modules and a robust
> knowledge base. Cloud Datalab enables analysis of your data on
> BigQuery, AI Platform, Compute Engine, and Cloud Storage using Python,
> SQL, and JavaScript (for BigQuery user-defined functions).
>
> IPython support
> Datalab is based on Jupyter (formerly IPython) so you
> can use a large number of existing packages for statistics, machine
> learning, etc. Learn from published notebooks and swap tips with a
> vibrant IPython community.

[Datalab > Doc > Resources > Cloud Datalab Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/resources/pricing):

> There is no charge for using Google Cloud Datalab. However, you do pay
> for any Google Cloud Platform resources you use with Cloud Datalab,
> for example:
>
> - Compute resources: You incur costs from the time of creation to the time of deletion of the Cloud Datalab VM instance. You can choose a
>   machine type. You can minimize costs by stopping Cloud
>   Compute Engine VM instances when you are not using them.
> - Storage resources: Notebooks are saved to Persistent Disk and backed up to Google Cloud Storage.
> - Data Analysis Services: You incur Google BigQuery costs when issuing SQL queries within Cloud Datalab notebooks. Also, when you use
>   Google Cloud Machine Learning, you may incur Cloud Machine Learning
>   Engine and/or Google Cloud Dataflow charges.
> - Other resources: You may incur costs for other API requests you make within the Cloud Datalab notebook environment.